# Negative sign of acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

This is the problem from our Physics textbook :

> *A player throws a ball upwards with an initial speed of 29.4 m s–1.
>   (a) Choose the x = 0 m and t = 0 s to be the location and time of the ball at its highest point, vertically downward direction to be the positive direction of
>   x-axis, and give the signs of position, velocity and acceleration of the ball
>   during its upward, and downward motion.*

Answer is :

> *x > 0 (upward and downward motion); v < 0 (upward), v > 0 (downward), a > 0
>   throughout;*

a > 0 is what is bothering me and I have done hours of searching and trying to understand.

Kindly explain all the parts of the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't do particular instance of homework questions. There is [a meta thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) that explains how to ask basic  questions in a way that we *will* answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acceleration is a vector $\mathbf{g}$ throughout the motion, and $\mathbf{g}$ is always pointing downward. Since you choose positive $x$ to be vertically downward, so $\mathbf{g}$ is along positive $x$ if we draw out the Cartesian coordinate, then $\mathbf{g}$ must have positive value, $\mathbf{g}=g\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}$. If you choose vertically upward to be $x>0$, then acceleration $\mathbf{g}$ has negative sign, $\mathbf{g}=-g\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}$. It's just the matter how you choose the $x>0,y>0$ directions. Draw a diagram of $v$, $g$, force on the ball with $(x,y)$ coordinates.

Comment: Since top is x=0, so position remains positive through out, and why velocity sign is - when going up and + when going down, as object never enters negative territory which is beyond x=0, so entire action takes place in the plus zone.

Answer (score 4):

> a > 0 is what is bothering me

The only acceleration in the problem is the acceleration of gravity, correct?

If you agree with that, then I think you'll agree that the acceleration is *always pointing downward* towards the Earth and thus, the acceleration *does not change sign for this problem*.

Now, from the problem statement:

> **vertically downward** direction to be the **positive direction**

So, what is the sign of the acceleration?